# Clients-server share timestamp over processors

Tags: c, timestamp, client-server

I have an application with many clients and one monitor server – each client send a log message to the server and the server should print the message (into log file) in the right order – while right order means the creating time (and not the arrival time) – i.e. the client should set the timestamp when creating the message.
My question: how to share the time? It looks like each host has different absolute time and it leads to wrong order and I need better way to “share” time.

Thanks.

Comment: my question is how long server waits for other clients to send message when it already has some buffered messages to print. Do you use any message queue at server side??

Comment: Just send the time with the log message, no? You don't actually care about time on the server, just the clients. Then make sure the clients are all time synced, ntp should do that nicely.

Comment: Keep the machines involved synchronised using for example `NTP`.